# append xml node using xmlserializer

Tags: android, xml, xmlserializer

i am a beginner with parsing and i want to create a XML by the help of the user.but i cannot append the xml.can you please help me out with the issue.i am sorry that i amy have not been able to format the code correctly.

```
public static String xmlSerialize(NewRecordDTO data) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException, IOException
{

    File sdCard=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir=new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/backup");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file=new File(dir,"diary.xml");
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream( file, true);


    XmlSerializer xmlserializer=Xml.newSerializer();
    StringWriter writer=new StringWriter();
    xmlserializer.setOutput(writer);
    xmlserializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);

    xmlserializer.startTag("", "LawyerRecords");
    xmlserializer.startTag("", "Record");

    xmlserializer.startTag("", "UID");
    xmlserializer.text(data.getUid());
    xmlserializer.endTag("", "UID");

    xmlserializer.startTag("", "PrevDate");
    xmlserializer.text(data.getPrev_date());
    xmlserializer.endTag("", "PrevDate");

    xmlserializer.startTag("", "CourtName");
    xmlserializer.text(data.getCaseName());
    xmlserializer.endTag("", "CourtName");

    xmlserializer.startTag("", "CaseNo");
    xmlserializer.text(data.getCaseNo());
    xmlserializer.endTag("", "CaseNo");

    xmlserializer.startTag("", "ForPartyName");
    xmlserializer.text(data.getForParty());
    xmlserializer.endTag("", "ForPartyName");

    xmlserializer.startTag("", "AgainstPartyName");
    xmlserializer.text(data.getAgainstParty());
    xmlserializer.endTag("", "AgainstPartyName");

    xmlserializer.startTag("", "Stage");
    xmlserializer.text(data.getStages());
    xmlserializer.endTag("", "Stage");

    xmlserializer.startTag("", "NextDate");
    xmlserializer.text(data.getNext_date());
    xmlserializer.endTag("", "NextDate");


    xmlserializer.endTag("", "Record");
    xmlserializer.endTag("", "LawyerRecords");
    xmlserializer.endDocument();

    String strData=writer.toString();
    fos.write(strData.getBytes());
    fos.close();

    return writer.toString();


}
```

The Xml is now giving an output like;

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<LawyerRecords>
<Record>
  <UID>gshs</UID>
  <PrevDate>dhshsh</PrevDate>
  <CourtName>shshd</CourtName>
  <CaseNo>shsshhs</CaseNo>
  <ForPartyName>sgffsdddvd ddhdhd ddf</ForPartyName>
  <AgainstPartyName>sddhssh shshsd</AgainstPartyName>
  <Stage>sgshdhdhsg ggggdhhhh</Stage>
  <NextDate>20-2-2014</NextDate>
 </Record>
 </LawyerRecords>
 <LawyerRecords>
   <Record>
    <UID>suprito</UID>
    <PrevDate>dhshsh</PrevDate>
    <CourtName>shshd</CourtName>
    <CaseNo>shsshhs</CaseNo><ForPartyName></ForPartyName>
    <AgainstPartyName>sddhssh shshsd</AgainstPartyName>
    <Stage>sgshdhdhsg ggggdhhhh</Stage> 
    <NextDate>20-2-2014</NextDate>
  </Record>
</LawyerRecords>
```

and my desired output is:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<LawyerRecords>
<Record>
  <UID>gshs</UID>
  <PrevDate>dhshsh</PrevDate>
  <CourtName>shshd</CourtName>
  <CaseNo>shsshhs</CaseNo>
  <ForPartyName>sgffsdddvd ddhdhd ddf</ForPartyName>
  <AgainstPartyName>sddhssh shshsd</AgainstPartyName>
  <Stage>sgshdhdhsg ggggdhhhh</Stage>
  <NextDate>20-2-2014</NextDate>
 </Record>

   <Record>
    <UID>suprito</UID>
    <PrevDate>dhshsh</PrevDate>
    <CourtName>shshd</CourtName>
    <CaseNo>shsshhs</CaseNo><ForPartyName></ForPartyName>
    <AgainstPartyName>sddhssh shshsd</AgainstPartyName>
    <Stage>sgshdhdhsg ggggdhhhh</Stage> 
    <NextDate>20-2-2014</NextDate>
  </Record>
</LawyerRecords>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You every-time create `xmlserializer.startTag("", "LawyerRecords");` and `xmlserializer.endTag("", "LawyerRecords");` for all records that's why you getting wrong output..

You have to add **LawyerRecords** tag only at initial and end not for all records.

add start tag **LawyerRecords** when add first record and add end tag **LawyerRecords** when add last record.

You can parse XML following methods.

[1)SAX Parser](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/#list5)

[2)DOM Parser](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/#list9)

[3)XML Pull Parser](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/#list10)

You can use `XmlSerializer` for generate XML.

Here is [Generate XML Code](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/#list11)

Comment: i am providing the xml output..please help..  [please check the link](http://pastebin.com/4MkVdHnT).i